# Visual Studio 2013 C# WinForms - Clicking on a control won't show properties

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Since this morning something is not working as usual while using Visual Studio 2013. Normally, when you press on a control (button, label etc) you also see it's properties in the right. However, now if I press on it the properties box stays empty, it shows no text, but the control is selected because it has that line made out of points around it. What do I do? I couldn't find the answer in other questions asked by others.

Thanks alot !

P.S. If a picture of the properties box is needed I will display one.

Comment: This will sound random, but do you have a tableadapter on the form?

Comment: just restart your visual studio and machine

Comment: Yes Justin. And rashfmnb, I did that aleardy.

Comment: There's a bug in VS '08 where if you have a tableadapter and a function named Fill, properties are left blank. I wonder if it's in '13 as well? There's a blog post on it here: https://shiftkeysoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/the-case-of-the-visual-studio-blank-properties-window/

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Justin. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always right-click on the control, and select properties from there. You can restart VS, which fixes MOST graphical anomalies. If that still doesn't work, restart your machine. And, if all else fails, reinstall VS. It's ridiculously easy to do these days..